# Jquery UI Animate background using scroll_pos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am working on changing the background of a div on scroll.  It works, but not consistently.  It sometimes doesn't make the change back when you scroll to the top position.  Other times it does, but there is a delay in the animation.  Any idea where I am going wrong here?

```
    var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 1) {
            $('.head').animate({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,1)'}, 500);
            $('.header li a, .header li a:visited, .header li a:active').animate({'color':'rgba(255,255,255,1)'},500);          
            } 
            if(scroll_pos < 1){
                $(".head").animate({'background-color':'rgba(223,223,223,0.8)'}, 500);
                $(".header li a, .header li a:visited, .header li a:active").animate({'color':'rgba(60,60,60,0.7)'}, 500);
            }
        });
```

I am using Jquery Mobile also, so my document ready function is actually;

```
    $(document).on('pageinit', function
```

Is it possible that this is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example of transitioning the color from black to white on scroll of the document, you could use a logic like this if you want the color to change dependent to the scroll position: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b57ng05a/)**

```
var length=255/($(document).height()-$(window).height());
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var amount=Math.ceil($(document).scrollTop()*length);
    $('body').css('background-color','rgb('+amount+','+amount+','+amount+')');
});
```